# Angular HTTP Get response is string not object

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I am trying to make an http get query to my local server, and then parse the results from the object returned to display to the user. No matter what I try, the data from the request AND the serverData object that I try and assign it to remain as strings. Please help I'm going crazy!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  showsFound: boolean = false;
  unknownShow: boolean = false;

  url: string;
  host: string;
  show: string;
  serverData: object;
  httpOptions: object = {
    responseType: 'json'
  }

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){
  }

  public getRecommendations(url) {
    var subString = url.split( '/' );
    this.host = subString[4];
    this.show = subString[6];
    this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:5002/api/v1/recommender/'+this.host+'/'+this.show, this.httpOptions)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(typeof data);            // logs 'string'
      this.serverData = <object>data;
      console.log(typeof this.serverData); // logs 'string'
    })
  }

}
```

Running console.log(data) gives the following output

```
{"name":"Url","data":["https:\/\/www.website.com\/shows\/show_name_1\/","https:\/\/www.website.com\/shows\/show_name_2\/"]}
```

I try to set as an object and pass to this.serverData but still it is a string

**EDIT**

Comments suggest it is to do with network response so have attached photos of query and response headers[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214466/discussion-on-question-by-francis-webb-angular-http-get-response-is-string-not-o).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this.serverData = data;

try this.serverData = JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part of the code

```js
 public getRecommendations(url) {
    var subString = url.split( '/' );
    this.host = subString[4];
    this.show = subString[6];
    this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:5002/api/v1/recommender/'+this.host+'/'+this.show, this.httpOptions)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(typeof data);            // logs 'string'
      this.serverData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(typeof this.serverData); // logs 'string'
    })
  }
```